# Using laravel queue with cron jobs on shared hosting

Tags: php, laravel, cron, queue

In this moment i have a shared hosting server.

In my app i want to use Laravel's queue system, but i can't maintain the command `php artisan queue:work` beacuse i can't install a `supervisor`.

With a little bit of an effort, i can move my app on a VPS, but i don't have much of experience with servers and i'm a little scared that my app will be offline much time.

Considering lack of experience on server side, i have this questions:

1. Is it ok to use Laravel queues with cron jobs? Can it break in any way?
2. Only for this problem should i upgrade to an VPS or i should remain on this shared hosting server ( i have ssh access here )?

Comment: Upgrade to a VPS and you can use a server management system like ploi.io or cloudways.com which makes it a lot easier to do this

Comment: @SalimDjerbouh Not helping, everyone can do it if have the budget.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Quick answer**: you should not use Laravel queues without a [process monitor](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/queues#running-the-queue-worker) such as Supervisor.

It all depends of what you want to achieve, but an alternative to queues would be using the laravel scheduler: you can trigger the scheduler with a cron task (every minute for example), and dispatch jobs easily.

And if you really want to use the queues, a solution could be to add your jobs to the queue, and process them using a cron task every minute running the following command: `php artisan queue:work`. But I would recommend the previous solution.

Comment: Ok.
Thank you very much for your answer!